# Decimal delimiter when viewing BigDecimal

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a class that contains fields of type String and BigDecimal. 
When displaying BigDecimal as a separator is dot I want to be a comma. I changed the coding on the Polish but is still dot.
When I use  `<f:convertNumber locale=""#{language.locale}"/>` works fine, but do not want to do that at every field because I have a lot of them

What is the best way to achieve this?

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>pl</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

**Language.java**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Language implements Serializable {

    private Locale locale;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getDefaultLocale();
    }

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

}
```

**view.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:fn="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/functions">
    <f:view locale="#{language.locale}">
        <h:head>
            <f:facet name="first">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
                <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="middle">
                <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css" />
                <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="default.css" />
                <h:outputScript name="js/bootstrap.js" />
            </f:facet>   
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:form id="menuForm">
                ...
                ...
                ...
                <h:outputText value="#{detail.1}" />    // string
                <h:outputText value="#{detail.2}" />    // bigdecimal
                ...
                ...
                ...
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to your locale in some way

> When I use `<f:convertNumber locale=""#{language.locale}"/>` works fine, but do not want to do that at every field because I have a lot of them

So if you don't want to do it in the client side, you will need to add a `getLocaleNumber()` (or similar) method to your bean in order to have the number in your desired format:

```
public String getLocalized(BigDecimal number) throws Exception {
    // get desired locale (maybe a constant will suit you better)
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("pl_PL"));
    return nf.format(number.doubleValue());
}
```

Comment: @BalusC actually I didn't search in google for this answer, I just gave OP *the solution I use normally*, maybe rounding is missing, but IMO approach of making a formatted getter in the bean is the correct way to go if you don't wanna use `<f:convertNumber>` repeatedly, if no, please kindly add your approach, I'm sure your's will be better, but sorry, I'm not agree about shooting in the dark, if an error is lack of JSF knowledge from my side